# SwiftUI collection of button with custom color changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[This is list of button i would like to implement in my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQVTR.png)

I need help to make this collection of button in SwiftUI. So whenever the user pressed a button the background will go darker from `Color(red: 0.64, green: 0.88, blue: 0.85, opacity: 1.0)` to `Color(red: 0.565, green: 0.783, blue: 0.757, opacity: 1.0)`, i tried using Picker but it picker doesn't have the functionality like a button that goes off after user have pressed.
Please help i'm new in SwiftUI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You will have to make your own picker to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var buttonNames = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    @State var selected: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ForEach(buttonNames, id: \.self) { button in
                
                HStack {
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    
                    Button {
                        selected = button
                    } label: {
                        Text(button)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    
                    
                }
                .padding(.vertical)
                .background(selected == button ? Color(red: 0.565, green: 0.783, blue: 0.757, opacity: 1.0) : Color(red: 0.64, green: 0.88, blue: 0.85, opacity: 1.0))
                

            }
            

        }
        .background(Color(red: 0.64, green: 0.88, blue: 0.85, opacity: 1.0))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Remove Foreach and type each button manually, then add Divider() between if you want the lines.